# Raspberry Pi3 light node initialization error

Tags: iri-node, light-node, raspberry-pi

I'would like to set up iri on a Raspberry Pi3 but when i try to build i receive the following error.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.RocksDB`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since RocksDB has problems with the ARM architecture, you need special version of RocksDB. Here is a complete tutorial: https://medium.com/biilabs/deploy-iota-fullnode-on-asus-tinker-board-fcd2cff8331f

A complete deployment script for IRI on the ARM architecture can be found here: https://github.com/deviceproof/iota-deploy

Comment: @alle.manfredi You could mark my answer if it fix your issue :) That's thankful enough :D